# Distance of a point from a line passing through two points.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, systems-of-equations, recreational-mathematics

Say I have these 2 lines represented as parametric equations like so:

$L1 : x= 1 + t, y = 0, z = 2 - t$

$L2 : x = t , y = t, z = 1 + t$

My question is:

Is there a way to find the distance (minimal) between those 2 lines **only by using the formula listed below?**

$$\frac{|| AB \times AP || }{ ||AB||}$$  (Distance of a point from a line passing through two points.)

$A$ is a point on $L1$

$B$ is a point on $L1$

$P$ is a point on $L2$

Comment: How do you define the distance between two lines **that aren't parallel** ?

Comment: probably OP means to say "minimal distance" between two lines

Comment: You  can see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_lines#Distance

Comment: @DonAntonio the minimal distance

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way.
$$
\frac{\lVert AB \times AP \rVert}{\lVert AB \rVert}
=
\frac{\lVert AB \rVert \lVert AP \rVert \sin \alpha}{\lVert AB \rVert}
=
\lVert AP \rVert \sin \alpha
$$
This formula only depends on the distance between $A$ and $P$ and that angle between the first line and $AP$ which is the shortest connection between $A$ and $P$, so it leaves out the direction of the second line.

We could rotate the second line around $P$ without changing the value of that formula, while that rotation might change the minimal distance between both lines.

For an example minimizing the (squared) distance over two parameters see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1801590/86776).

Comment: That would depend how literally you take the “only by using the formula …” part of the question. You could plug in a general point $P$ on ghe second line given by its parametrisation, square it, and get a quadratic polynomial in the parameter $t$. This is, of course, easy to minimise.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen can you please explain more

Comment: @HashWizard See the link in the last sentence of my answer.

Comment: Simply this: Pick two points on $L_1$, and call them $A$ and $B$. For example, the one with $t=0$ and the one with $t=1$. Write $P=(t,t,1+t)$. Calculate the cross product $AB\times AP$. It will be some vector in which each component is a first degree polynomial in $t$. Calculate the squared norm of the cross product. It will be a quadratic polynomial in $t$. Find the $t$ value that minimizes it. Take the square root, since we used the squared norm before. Divide by $\|AB\|$. Done.