# Distance between 2 skew lines with addon restrictions

Tags: calculus, recreational-mathematics

Can you find the distance between 2 skew lines using only the formula for the distance of a point and a line passing through 2 points (given below)?

||AB×AP||/ ||AB||

Comment: where is $A,B,P$?

Comment: skew lines=curves.?

Comment: Google for it and you will find an answer

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2143777/265466)?